# Group by in columns and rows, counts and percentages per day

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have a table that has data like following.

```
attr            |time         
----------------|--------------------------
abc             |2018-08-06 10:17:25.282546
def             |2018-08-06 10:17:25.325676
pqr             |2018-08-05 10:17:25.366823
abc             |2018-08-06 10:17:25.407941
def             |2018-08-05 10:17:25.449249
```

I want to group them and count by attr column row wise and also create additional columns in to show their counts per day and percentages as shown below.

```
attr            |day1_count| day1_%| day2_count| day2_%     
----------------|----------|-------|-----------|-------
abc             |2         |66.6%  | 0         | 0.0%
def             |1         |33.3%  | 1         | 50.0%
pqr             |0         |0.0%   | 1         | 50.0%
```

I'm able to display one count by using group by but unable to find out how to even seperate them to multiple columns. I tried to generate day1 percentage with

```
SELECT attr, count(attr), count(attr) / sum(sub.day1_count) * 100 as percentage from (
    SELECT attr, count(*) as day1_count FROM my_table WHERE DATEPART(week, time) = DATEPART(day, GETDate()) GROUP BY attr) as sub
    GROUP BY attr;
```

But this also is not giving me correct answer, I'm getting all zeroes for percentage and count as 1. Any help is appreciated. I'm trying to do this in Redshift which follows postgresql syntax.

Comment: Do you need it only for 2 days? What if your table contains more then 2 days?

Comment: My requirement is to do it for 6 days. But I wanted to expand upon once I get answer for two.

Comment: Four times nearly the same answer. Did you expect something else?

Comment: No, I lost access to database to test query. I'm trying to run the query. I will mark the answer once I can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's nail the logic before presenting:

```
with CTE1 as
(
select attr, DATEPART(day, time) as theday, count(*) as thecount
from MyTable
)
, CTE2 as
(
select theday, sum(thecount) as daytotal
from CTE1
group by theday
)
select t1.attr, t1.theday, t1.thecount, t1.thecount/t2.daytotal as percentofday
from CTE1 t1
inner join CTE2 t2
on t1.theday = t2.theday
```

From here you can pivot to create a day by day if you feel the need

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to enhance the query  @johnHC btw if you needs for 7days then you have to those days in case when

```
with CTE1 as
(
select attr, time::date as theday, count(*) as thecount
from t group by attr,time::date
)
, CTE2 as
(
select theday, sum(thecount) as daytotal
from CTE1
group by theday
)
,
CTE3 as
(
select t1.attr, EXTRACT(DOW FROM  t1.theday) as day_nmbr,t1.theday, t1.thecount, t1.thecount/t2.daytotal as percentofday
from CTE1 t1
inner join CTE2 t2
on t1.theday = t2.theday
) 
select CTE3.attr,
max(case when day_nmbr=0 then CTE3.thecount end) as day1Cnt,
max(case when day_nmbr=0 then percentofday end) as day1,
max(case when day_nmbr=1 then CTE3.thecount end) as day2Cnt,
max( case when day_nmbr=1 then percentofday end) day2 
from  CTE3 group by CTE3.attr
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/54ace/20

Answer (score 0):

In case that you have only 2 days:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3bdad/3 (days descending as in your example from left to right)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3bdad/5 (days ascending)

The main idea is already mentioned in the other answers. Instead of joining the CTEs for calculating the values I am using window functions which is a bit shorter and more readable I think. The pivot is done the same way.

```
 SELECT 
    attr, 
    COALESCE(max(count) FILTER (WHERE day_number = 0), 0) as day1_count,         -- D
    COALESCE(max(percent) FILTER (WHERE day_number = 0), 0) as day1_percent, 
    COALESCE(max(count) FILTER (WHERE day_number = 1), 0) as day2_count,
    COALESCE(max(percent) FILTER (WHERE day_number = 1), 0) as day2_percent
    /*
       Add more days here
    */
FROM(
    SELECT *, (count::float/count_per_day)::decimal(5, 2) as percent             -- C
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            attr, 
            MAX(time::date) OVER () - time::date as day_number,                  -- B
            count(*) OVER (partition by time::date, attr) as count,              -- A
            count(*) OVER (partition by time::date) as count_per_day 
        FROM test_table
    )s
)s

GROUP BY attr
ORDER BY attr
```

A counting the rows per day and counting the rows per day AND `attr`

B for more readability I convert the date into numbers. Here I take the difference between current date of the row and the maximum date available in the table. So I get a counter from 0 (first day) up to n - 1 (last day)

C calculating the percentage and rounding

D pivot by filter the day numbers. The `COALESCE` avoids the `NULL` values and switched them into 0. To add more days you can multiply these columns.

Edit: Made the day counter more flexible for more days; new SQL Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I see this as conditional aggregation.  But you need to get an enumerator for the date for the pivoting.  So:

```
SELECT attr, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE day_number = 1) as day1_count, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE day_number = 1) / cnt as day1_percent, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE day_number = 2) as day2_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE day_number = 2) / cnt as day2_percent
FROM (SELECT attr,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY time::date DESC) as day_number,
             1.0 * COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY attr) as cnt
      FROM test_table
     ) s
GROUP BY attr, cnt
ORDER BY attr;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3bdad/11) is a SQL Fiddle.